# Centering an Absolute Image using %

Tags: css, background-image, css-position, centering

I am having some problems using percentages to horizontally center an absolutely positioned image. It it for a fluid site and so I need the erasers.png image to be centered in the background. I need to be able to control its size in percentages, so I dont think I can make it a background image.

Is there a way to do this? Or is there a better way to accomplish the same thing?

http://jsfiddle.net/vzPUw/6/

Comment: Are you using the same image as mention in your example which has 2 X 1 px dimension which will come in center of your content without any repeat?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely position a wrapper for the image (instead of the image), apply text-align:center to  the wrapper, and set its left and right properties to 0px. The wrapper will be the same with as the header, but will be taken out of the flow, while the image can continue to behave as an inline element, so that centering works, but will be isolated to the context of the wrapper.

HTML:

```
<span id="erasersWrapper">
    <img id="toperasers" src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14080718/Final/images/erasers.png" alt="Erasers">
</span>
```

CSS:

```
#erasersWrapper{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but something is not working right. http://jsfiddle.net/vzPUw/7/ Any ideas?

Comment: Try setting the left and right properties to -10000px. You also need to still specify the height of the graphic as a percentage of its container. Not sure of your exact desired visual effect, but this fiddle incorporates the principles, I believe: http://jsfiddle.net/vzPUw/8/  ... NOTE: it's appearing different in each browser --  so it will need a little more work -- but the effect of maintaining the relationship between the images' proportions while scaling is working.

Comment: This is an great start. Thanks for the help. It seems to work in Chrome.